# Curl Response takes very long

Tags: php, json, curl

my Curl Response takes very long. Is there any way to make it faster?

This is an api for checking the status from elevators.

```
        $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.deutschebahn.com/fasta/v2/facilities?type=ELEVATOR&stationnumber=1401",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $result = json_decode($response, true);
```

Comment: more than likely it's the remote server which is taking the time to respond. (You could verify this, by sending the same request using a different client, e.g. a testing tool like PostMan). And if it's not your server, probably there is not a lot you can do about it. P.S. Elevators always take ages to arrive...that is a fact of life ;-)

Comment: It's the Deutsche Bahn... **of course** it's slow and delays the time of arrival ;)